# Can i use aws reserved instance with elastic beanstalk

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, aws-reserved-instances

How do i use an AWS reserved instance with elastic beanstalk. I only see tutorials on using reserved instance on ec2 instance but not elastic beanstalk.

Comment: I'm sorry, i don't seem to understand that and the other posts about this that is why i created this.

Comment: You do not "create" a reserved instance. Reserved instances are a billing discount and a capacity assurance. For each Amazon EC2 billing hour, if an EC2 instance is being used that matches an available Reserved Instance, then the billing discount is applied. The explanations on the other Question are accurate.

Comment: But if i just get a reserved instance will it cover the elastic beanstalk?

Comment: If you get a Reserved Instance for, say, an `m5.large` and you use Elastic Beanstalk to launch an `m5.large` and there is no other `m5.large` running at the time then, yes, the billing discount associated with the Reserved Instance will apply to the EC2 instance launched by Elastic Beanstalk. More info: [How Reserved Instances Are Applied - Amazon EC2](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/apply_ri.html)